# Delete from db multiple rows Drupal

Tags: mysql, database, drupal

i have a problem i need to delete from cache table specific rows. I have like 3 rows to delete by one submit.

```
 cache_73_content 
 cache_73_work 
 cache_73_header
```

I tried like this :

```
$cache_delete = sprintf('cache_%s', $form_state['values']['node_tid']) . '%';
db_delete('cache')
->condition('cid', $cache_delete)
->execute();
```

But didn't work. Please need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would make more sense to use the API:

```
$cache_delete = sprintf('cache_%s', $form_state['values']['node_tid']);
cache_clear_all($cache_delete, 'cache', TRUE);
```

If you must use the database directly:

```
$cache_delete = sprintf('cache_%s', $form_state['values']['node_tid']) . '%';
db_delete('cache')
  ->condition('cid', $cache_delete, 'LIKE')
  ->execute();
```